# uploading scores to a text file

Tags: blackberry

I am developing the scores part of a blackberry game.The scores are generated and I want to take username as input and display his resp score. How can I retrieve the scores in the text file?I am using text file as the db. the Updation is a problem and I have no clue how to go ahead with it.As many of u know, BB supports only few of Java APIs so please help me how to store and display player's name and score as and when new player plays the game.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you could store the scores in a text file and then retrieve the scores later.  However, BlackBerry provides other classes for saving data that would probably work better for what you want to do.  I would recommend you put the scores into a Hashtable and then store that hashtable with the [PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html) class.  The code to do that would look something like this:

```
Hashtable scoresTable = new HashTable();
PersistentObject perstObj = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(<UNIQUE KEY>);
perstObj.setContents(scoresTable);
perstObj.commit();
```

If you really want a text file then the code to open it would look like this:

```
FileConnection fileConn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(<FILE URL>);
```

Comment: Thanks alot Jonathan for taking ur valuable time out for me...I wil surely look into Hashtables....I had one query, I wanted to display name followed by scores.I will sort the file based on scores....Does hashtable allow taking 2 keys? names and scores?

Comment: Your comment would probably be better served by a new question but hashtables take one key and one value.  You can think of a hashtable as being like an array but rather than being indexed by numbers hashtables are indexed by objects.  If you want to save multiple scores for each username then you could create your own class to hold multiple scores and then store that as the value in the hashtable.